# Networking Setup Of An OpenStack-Based Environment

Tags: 14.04, server, openstack

**Big Picture Aim**: Have an OpenStack system (consists of 7 machines with Ubuntu Server Installed) to host a single application.

Here is my current setting:

1. **Machines**: 7 servers running Ubuntu server.
2. **Networking**: A router/switch, where a static IP linked its master port. The rest of 7 slaved ports are physically linked to the 7 machines.

**Assumption and Question**

Assume the following addresses linked to the router/switch's master port:

- Static IP: 11.11.11.11
- Gateway  : 10.10.10.10
- subnet   :  9. 9. 9. 9

Question is, what will be the network interfaces (i.e., /etc/network/interfaces) of each of these 7 machines?

Answer (score 1):

The official method is to use the [Landscape OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack).

If not using the autopilot, the next recommended method is to use [MAAS](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/maas) to commission the machines, then use [Juju](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/juju) to deploy OpenStack.

In these scenarios, MAAS handles DHCP for the broadcast domain behind your router ("LAN") and neutron handles DHCP for the instances in your tenant network(s).

When you deploy services with Juju and MAAS, the machines are automatically provisioned and configured, including their network interfaces.  Even for just a handful of servers, this makes deployment and management quite nice.  Bear in mind that the neutron-gateway unit needs to have two NICs connected.

It might end up looking something like this, assuming that you're using /24 networks with 255.255.255.0 subnet masks throughout:

```
11.11.11.11/24 <-WAN-> (YourRouter w/o DHCP@LAN) <-LAN-> 10.10.10.1/24
  MAAS @ 10.10.10.2/24
  MAAS configured to handle DHCP and DNS
  MAAS DHCP pool:              10.10.10.10  through .127
  Neutron floating IP range:   10.10.10.128 through .254
  Juju units @ 10.10.10.10 through .?, automatically assigned
```

Other recommended docs and links:

- [MAAS Documentation](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/index.html#)
- [A 4-machine Juju bundle example:  Ubuntu OpenStack "Basic"](https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers/openstack/)